# How to split javascript array of object with specific condition using lodash/underscorejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js, lodash

I have array of objects like this:

```
var data = [
 {
    type : "parent",
    name : "A"
 },
 {
    type : "child",
    name : "1"
 },
 {
    type : "child",
    name : "2"
 },
 {
    type : "parent",
    name : "B"
 },
 {
    type : "child",
    name : "3"
 }
]
```

and I want to move child objects into parent objects, splitted by the parrent object (there is no given key from child object is belonged to which parrent). So it's only separate by the parent object. To be simple I want to change the array into :

```
[
  {
    type : "parent",
    name : "A",
    child: [
        {
            type : "child",
            name : "1"
        },
        {
            type : "child",
            name : "2"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    type : "parent",
    name : "B",
    child: [
        {
            type : "child",
            name : "3"
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

I have read lodash about [chunk](https://lodash.com/docs#chunk) but it's no use.

Comment: This is a reduction. Use _.reduce() for this.

Comment: you mean name:1 and 2 instead of aa and ab, right?

Comment: Sorry, yeah I miss that @mplungjan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use either the native [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function or lodash's [`reduce`](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce):

```js
var data = [{
    type: "parent",
    name: "A"
  },
  {
    type: "child",
    name: "1"
  },
  {
    type: "child",
    name: "2"
  },
  {
    type: "parent",
    name: "B"
  },
  {
    type: "child",
    name: "3"
  }
];

// If using _.reduce then use:
// var newData = _.reduce(data, function(arr, el) {...}, []);
var newData = data.reduce(function(arr, el) {
  if (el.type === 'parent') {
    // If el is pushed directly it would be a reference
    // from the original data object
    arr.push({
      type: el.type,
      name: el.name,
      child: []
    });
  } else {
    arr[arr.length - 1].child.push({
      type: el.type,
      name: el.name
    });
  }

  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(newData);
```

UPDATE: Small changes using newer ES language features

```js
const data = [{
    type: "parent",
    name: "A"
  },
  {
    type: "child",
    name: "1"
  },
  {
    type: "child",
    name: "2"
  },
  {
    type: "parent",
    name: "B"
  },
  {
    type: "child",
    name: "3"
  }
];

const newData = data.reduce((arr, el) => {
  if (el.type === 'parent') {
    // If el is pushed directly it would be a reference
    // from the original data object
    arr.push({...el, child: []});
  } else {
    arr[arr.length - 1].child.push({...el});
  }

  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a lodash solution that may be a bit easier to understand. [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPBQLW?editors=001)

A few notes:

- this modifies the incoming data object - if that's a problem we can toss in some `_.clone()` calls.
- This will only work if each parent has 26 or fewer children, because of the `name: "ab"` pattern you picked

```
var lastParent;
var result = _.chain(data)
  .groupBy(function (item) {
    if (item.type === 'parent') lastParent = item.name
    return lastParent
  })
  .map(function (group) {
    var parent = _.first(group)
    parent.child = _.chain(group)
      .slice(1)
      .map(function (child, index) {
        child.name = parent.name.toLowerCase() + String.fromCharCode(index + 97)
        return child 
      })
      .value()
    return parent
  })
  .value()

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain javascript version:

```
var newArr = [];
var j=0;
var k=0;
for (var i = 0; i <data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].type == 'parent'){
        newArr[j] = data[i];
        newArr[j].children = [];
        j++;
        k=0;
    } 
    else {
        data[i].name = newArr[j-1].name.toLowerCase() + String.fromCharCode(k + 97)
        newArr[j-1].children[k] =data[i];
        k++;
    }
}
console.log(newArr)
```

I am assuming here that the parent is *always* placed before the children, as provided in your example data.

Also, it would be good if you can prevent parents with 26+ children. This would cause `String.fromCharCode(k + 97)` to print strange characters. For this, see http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (ele in data)
{
    if (!data[ele].hasOwnProperty('child') && data[ele].type=='parent')
    {
        data[ele].child = [];
        while(data[parseInt(ele) + 1] && data[parseInt(ele) + 1].type == 'child')
        {
            data[ele].child.push({type: data[parseInt(ele) + 1].type, name:data[parseInt(ele) + 1].name});
            data.splice(parseInt(ele) + 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simple loop:

```js
var current, parent, result = [], i = 0;

while(current = data[i++]){

    if(current.type === "parent"){
        current.child = [];
        result.push(current);
        parent = current
    }else{
        current.name = (parent.name + String.fromCharCode(parent.child.length + 97)).toLowerCase();
        parent.child.push(current)
    }

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wZVanG/vp2tz54n/)**